# How to convert Word page numbers to PDF page labels?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, page-numbers

I have a long Microsoft Word document, with some introductory pages. The following body pages are numbered from the last page of the previous document. My question is how to carry those page numbers through a PDF conversion such that the PDF uses them as page labels. I can set the labels manually in Acrobat, but I would prefer an automated solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only control Word has is the page numbers that it puts on the page, which do not necessarily correspond to the page numbers used by Acrobat or other pdf software. PDF software does not pay attention to fictional page numbers but rather looks to the actual number of pages.

You can have your headings convert to pdf bookmarks.

You can start your page numbers at any number you want in the Word document using the Format Page Numbers dialog. Those will be the page numbers that show up on the pdf. However, regardless of that numbering, the pdf reader will see the first page as page 1.

Here is my writing explaining [Page Numbers in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers). Again, these do not translate to how pdf documents number pages but will control what numbers display in the pdf file.